# How to fetch application specific url's by using wireshark in Windows-8/10?

Tags: wireshark

Its my first time using wireshark and I am encountered with one major problem i.e **How will i sniff url/api that a particular application/software is hitting which is installed in Windows-8/10 by using wireshark?**. Currently I am receiving a lot of url's and it is not possible to filter them out by any way. So i want to know is there any way to do that for a particular application like by setting some filters, etc. Please help me to solve this probelm.

**What I have tried so far:**
I have already tried by setting filters for some ports but still there are a lot of url's and the port numbers that application will hit are not known yet.

Answer (score 0):

With wireshark, you can use the `http.host` filter.

To do an exact match, you can do:
`http.host == "exact.hostname"`

To check if a URL contains a specific string, do:
`http.host.contains "partial.hostname"`

And to use regular expressions, you can use `http.host.matches`

For example:
`http.host matches "(?i)website\.name"` will match the hostname `website.name` and be case insensitive. (the `\.` is used to escape the `.` character in the regular expression, as the `.` character has a special meaning within regular expressions).

**EDIT:**
The `==` above will match the given URLs, but if you would like to filter out known URLs, you can use `!=` (not equal to) instead.
Or you can do `!(http.host == "exact.hostname")`. This negates the result of the first option above.

Comment: But how do i know the host names used by that application? Isn't there any filter to setup by application name?

Comment: @suv Are you trying to filter out certain applications? Please provide an example of what you are trying to do

Comment: yes, I want to filter out API/URL's by one Android Emulator running as an application in Windows OS. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: @suv see the edit in my answer

Comment: Thanks but i think you misunderstood me, I mean that i don't know the url's, what i know is just application name.

Comment: Is there a specific application you're using? What protocol does it it use? You could also filter by protocol

Comment: The application name is "Koplayer"